# CSV data analysis with hidden variable's names

Tags: analysis

I have an analytic problem.

In order to do an interview, the employer gave me a sample of data (csv data) without any indication of the names of variables. There only numeric data. He tolds me to analyze the data and found the relationships betwen data. As the first time I work with data without variable's name. Can you help me to found the best way to analyze it.

Here the 16 first line of the data.

Thank you very much

BEsts!

> "";"A";"B";"C";"D";"E";"G";"H";"I";"J"
>   "1";0,448161832988262;2;2;114,646534434721;3,30110318594957;-19,599488176302;234,434198671982;20,6532414748726;15,1932268216357
>   "2";0,432204742450267;1;2;85,7605207392913;3,62111444347777;-1,15239499472225;178,211501645965;16,9600753825141;-0,112499563201146 "3";0,568398675648496;1;2;71,6164756272189;7,69368362802501;24,7537090689179;153,913075791719;28,2888808213224;-0,104468251047106
>   "4";0,349178678821772;2;2;121,170146136389;3,37847601607964;11,7925265579597;252,551708711339;18,621791522593;6,38200554369286
>   "5";0,537820372032002;2;1;63,9725158637857;8,09451459803737;45,2679414663975;142,05393538719;22,3210943859884;2,63072085022351
>   "6";0,311805972829461;2;1;105,86608851945;7,00105784025606;56,7118971691138;207,671845532346;28,1108882120601;6,91708052471079
>   "7";0,188992844894528;2;1;91,4349746370189;4,22115610670039;113,719882708266;191,935903422313;27,722226329035;1,96456921716711
>   "8";0,220268326113001;2;1;96,9513989045572;3,30097548353886;41,9359256486865;193,983671256507;21,1632614867063;0,897974894012737
>   "9";0,745850879931822;2;2;117,920731392395;0,708984633432214;12,0311471051253;252,479427305587;16,1589645742755;13,4663055003645
>   "10";0,685712045058608;2;1;114,761284685084;-2,05310178438932;78,7495516682929;241,262975712287;29,0455805154816;0,628022028133988
>   "11";0,288209964288399;2;1;72,581830232794;6,64981545368408;45,2083742548179;148,12776449076;27,9515510556148;7,63068446314225
>   "12";0,837000070838258;2;1;92,5181661942909;0,0636188206698255;41,882160754504;199,975615311369;13,5301385749224;2,80857064980119
>   "13";0,725813006050885;2;2;119,512257003768;-1,14732052387933;13,9914669274313;243,515192596543;13,7178765507419;10,7559454559754
>   "14";0,448982792440802;2;1;76,9548634545701;6,22868004513269;36,4101586275915;159,127996500245;25,6106129292056;20,5549219150393
>   "15";0,000250126933678985;2;2;78,7042365624531;6,87908300161039;33,3968162297511;155,114586653932;25,8772230949845;2,66564733215586
>   "16";0,430642496794462;2;1;60,8333601287592;6,01562443738694;38,8547948159146;122,277246640109;22,1027759089393;4,64118405160815

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do would be to plot the data into a line chart, with the record index (first column in your data) along the X axis, and data for each column plotted as a separate line. That will give you first idea about the "behavior" of each column, and hopefully also show some relations between the columns.

The next steps will proceed from what you can figure out from this first glance.